# Foreign Key to Partitioned Table

Tags: partitioning, foreign-key, postgresql-13, postgresql-14

I have the following basic schema for an ever growing huge *transaction* table. In order to query speedup & phase out stale data, I need to partition by time & country.

```
CREATE TABLE transaction (
  id          BIGSERIAL,
  time_stamp  TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  country     TEXT NOT NULL,
  ... 
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Question is, how can I define in Postgres `13` or `14` such a (partitioned or sub-partitioned or multi-column partitioned) table so that other tables can explicitly link to with foreign keys only on the `id` column?

The naive approach produces:

```
ERROR: unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns
```

Comment: Well, you can't, as you have discovered. A foreign key _must_ reference a unique constraint on the parent, and every unique constraint on a partitioned table _must_ include the partitioning key.

Comment: Bummer :-( I would have imagined this was a common real-life use case.

Comment: Could re-defining the `transaction.id` column to act as both partition & primary key via a custom `CREATE TYPE` that bundles (id, time_stamp, country) be a recommended alternative?

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. Myself, I wouldn't try to be fancier than necessary by defining custom types.